# jquery/bootstrap/font awesome accordion menu - how to open active link automatically

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, moodle, font-awesome

I've managed to get this fiddle to the point where I can still use the main heading anchor as a link AND still use the icon as an accordion trigger, whilst using Twitter Bootstrap and Font Awesome icons.

The only issue is, when I click on a link (in Moodle) the refreshed page doesn't remember that one of the menu options should stay open.

I have set submenu item 3.2 to active, but don't have the code needed to notice that item 3 through 3.7 should be expanded.

Any help appreciated, and if this fiddle helps you as is, then great!

http://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/x3P6u/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function toggleAccordion(li) {
    if (li.hasClass('active')) {
        li.removeClass('active');
        $('.sub-menu', li).slideUp();
        $(li).removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-right');
    } else {
        $('li.active .sub-menu').slideUp();
        $('li i').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-right');
        $('li i').removeClass('active');
        li.addClass('active');
        $('.sub-menu', li).slideDown();
        $(li).removeClass('fa-caret-right').addClass('fa-caret-down');
    }
};
$('.book_sidebar ul li').click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    toggleAccordion($(this));
});
$('.book_sidebar ul li a').click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    toggleAccordion($(this).parent());
});
```

OK, so it took a few iterations and some great help from Tony and Codecademy, but the final code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function toggleAccordion(li) {
    if (li.hasClass('active')) {
        li.removeClass('active');
        $('.sub-menu', li).slideUp();
        $(li).removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-right');
    } else {
        $('li.active .sub-menu').slideUp();
        $('li.active.fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-right');
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        li.addClass('active');
        $('.sub-menu', li).slideDown();
        $('.sub-menu', li).children().removeClass('active');
        $(li).removeClass('fa-caret-right').addClass('fa-caret-down');
    }
};
$('.book_sidebar ul li').click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    toggleAccordion($(this));
});
$('.book_sidebar ul li a').click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    toggleAccordion($(this).parent());
});

function checkActive(li) {
    if (li.hasClass('active')) {
        if (li.parent().hasClass('sub-menu')) {
            toggleAccordion($('.active').parent(".sub-menu").parent());
        } else {
            toggleAccordion($('.active'));
        }
    } else {
        /* do nothing */;
    }
};
/*$('.book_sidebar ul li a').click(function(ev) {
    $('.book_sidebar .sub-menu').not($(this).parents('.sub-menu')).slideUp();
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next('i').remove();
    $(this).append('<i class="sidebar-icon fa fa-caret-down"></i>');
});*/
checkActive($('.active'));
/* toggleAccordion($('.active').parent(".sub-menu").parent());*/
```

});

You can see it work at http://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/L8vS3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggleAccordion on document ready, but your toggleAccordion is setup to use the parent list items instead of the sub menus which you have set using the active class.

```
toggleAccordion($('.active').parent(".sub-menu").parent());
```

The problem with this solution is your 3.2 item is still going to have the active class and you will be adding the active class to the 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/x3P6u/20/

Comment: Thanks Tony - I wasn't ignoring you, I just tried to take it a bit further.  You put me onto the right track!!  http://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/cpGXg/

Comment: np, did you figure it out?

Comment: Not quite - when I toggled a different icon the current icon didn't have active removed properly.  I fixed that with http://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/L8vS3/